# using numeric string begins with 0 in preparedstatement

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have encountered some problems when using numeric string begins with 0 as parameter value in preparedstatement,the query looks like below:

```
pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select count(*) from tbl_mer_info where mer_code =?");
pstmt.setString(1,"0825");
ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
```

but unfortunately the resultset is empty, it doesn't turn out as expected.
just for infomation: I am using Oracle as database,the table looks like:

```
tbl_mer_info: column_1, column_2, mer_code(CHAR(15 BYTE)
```

I find some alternative solutions which works,however I can't understand why solution 1 works but the solution above does not work. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Solution 1:

```
pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select count(*) from tbl_mer_info where mer_code like ?");      
pstmt.setString(1,"0825%");
```

Solution 2:

```
String str="select count(*) from tbl_mer_info where mer_code ='0825'";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(str);
```

Comment: well `like` is not the same as `equals`.  Also as the `mer_code` in the DB is `CHAR` and not `VARCHAR` you maybe find that it is padded with spaces

Comment: What happens if you use VARCHAR instead of CHAR as the column type?  In Oracle, CHAR usually means a fixed width field, with a bunch of trailing spaces.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thank you, you are right, it works now. <3

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Thank you, I tried as the way you suggested, it works now. bisous!

Comment: Change the type of `mer_code` to `varchar2(15)`. You also can try: `...... where mer_code = RPAD( ?, 15)`, but this is awkward solution, it ties the query to the data model. An advice - do not use CHAR datatype in your tables,

Comment: @krokodilko Thank you for your suggestion, in fact CHAR is used because the database is created 15 years ago and that column is relatively stable at that time so it is intended to be used like that. VARCHAR is more convenient at the cost of lower reading and writing speed than CHAR.